# jQuery slice random amount of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, random

I'm a beginner at best with scripting so I'm hoping someone can help me if this is possible.

I'm using this script pieced together from research to randomize the divs displayed on a page, but I would like to make it display a random amount of them as well, instead of set slice amounts `(0,6)`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var divs = $("div.picture").get().sort(function(){ 
        return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;
    })

   $(divs).appendTo(divs[0].parentNode).show();
   $('.gallery').find('.picture').slice(0,6).remove();     
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: So generate a random number based of the length...TADA

Comment: ok maybe I was just thinking it was more complicated, found my answer so will post here for future readers.

added

    var X = 1+ Math.floor(Math.random()*16)

so simple :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `parseInt(Math.random() * (max - min) + min, 10)` to get the random number. It will give you and interval of `[min, max]` slices.